# DRF create user in nested serializer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

Hello all i am trying to create an user in via API with nested serializers in django rest framework and i am having some issues:

Here is my code:

```
class AffiliateRegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Affiliate
    fields = ('phone','address','state','city','ZIP','country','company','web_name','web_url','web_desc','payee_name','monthly_visits',)
```

and my second serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    '''
        Registering a new user with Affiliate Profile
    '''

    affiliate = AffiliateRegisterSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','first_name','last_name','email','password','affiliate',)
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
        read_only_fields = ('id','affiliate',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        affiliate_data = validated_data.pop('affiliate')
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        Affiliate.objects.create(user=user, **affiliate_data)
        return user
```

and this is my view:

```
class AffiliateSignUp(generics.CreateAPIView):
    '''
        API endpoint for Affiliate Users registration
    '''

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    def create(self, request):
            serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)

            if serializer.is_valid():
                    serializer.save()
                    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
            return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

> How can i send an POST request via AngularJS to create the user and the profile instantly?

I am trying to POST a nested object via AngularJs but it says:

> affiliate: ["This field is required."]

If i go directly from the backend via url: /api/affilaite it registers the user very good, but the only problem here which i am strugling is,

> How to send the POST request with a nested object in javascript.

and here is my javascript code:

```
data:$httpParamSerializerJQLike({
                'first_name':$scope.userData['first_name'],
                'last_name':$scope.userData['last_name'],
                'username':$scope.userData['username'],
                'password':$scope.userData['password'],
                'email':$scope.userData['email'],
                affiliate:{
                'phone':$scope.userData['phone'],
                'address':$scope.userData['address'],
                'state':$scope.userData['state'],
                'city':$scope.userData['city'],
                'ZIP':$scope.userData['ZIP'],
                'country':$scope.userData['country'],
                'company':$scope.userData['company'],
                'web_url':$scope.userData['webUrl'],
                'web_name':$scope.userData['webName'],
                'web_desc':$scope.userData['webDesc'],
                //'web_category':$scope.userData ['webCategory'],
                'payee_name':$scope.userData['payeeName'],
                'monthly_visits':$scope.userData['monthly_visits']
                }
              }
```

please help me guys :D i am struggling :P

Comment: hmm. this is odd. looks like you are sending `affiliate` in the payload. can you print `request.data` in the view to verify what is there?

Comment: affiliate[ZIP]: "1230"
affiliate[address]: "balindollska bb"
affiliate[city]: "Gostivar"
affiliate[company]: "Maxleads"
affiliate[country]: "Macedonia"
affiliate[monthly_visits]: "132523"
affiliate[payee_name]: "gentz"
affiliate[phone]: "71666022"
affiliate[state]: "Macedonia"
affiliate[web_desc]: "Affiliate MArketing Network"
affiliate[web_name]: "Maxleads"
affiliate[web_url]: "http://www.maxleads.net"
email: "gentz@gentz.com"
first_name: "gentian"
last_name: "Elmazi"
password: "gentz"
username: "gentz"

Comment: whats the exact data? can you update the answer?

Comment: how do you mean the exact data ?

Comment: please paste exact content of `print(request.data)`. what you pasted above is not valid data.

Comment: {"username": "gentz", "first_name": "gentz", "last_name": "gentz", "email": "gentz@gentz.com", "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$24000$Gg9AuNVj1lK6$RdpniPgQi14MWafD60t1nii0vQDjiO9hWtzDZrRn5l4=", "affiliate": {"phone": "71666022", "address": "gentz", "state": "gentz", "city": "gentz", "ZIP": "gentz", "country": "gentz", "company": "gentz", "web_name": "gentz", "web_url": "http://www.maxleads.net", "web_desc": "gentz", "payee_name": "gentz", "monthly_visits": 125235}} I hope this is OK,

Comment: looks like all data is present. something else must be going on.

Comment: this data is when i do a POST from the backend /api/affiliate/, this it works, but when i POST from front-end in AngularJS it says that affilaite[this field is required]

Comment: @miki725 can u show me how to see the print(request.data)

Comment: data: "usernamefirst_namelast_nameaffiliate[state]affiliate[ZIP]affiliate[country]affiliate[web_desc]affiliate[phone]affiliate[monthly_visits]affiliate[company]affiliate[city]affiliate[web_name]passwordemailaffiliate[payee_name]affiliate[web_url]" this is what i am sending :( omg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The problem was that i was sending an QueryDict application/x-www-form-urlencoded

so from the front-end i changed the

```
method:'POST',
            url:'/api/URL/',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            dataType: 'json',
```

and i send a nested object.

So this does create a user with a user profile instantly.

thank you all for the  support

Answer (score 1):

You have `affiliate` as read only in the serializer `Meta`: `read_only_fields = ('id','affiliate',)`.

> read_only
>
> Read-only fields are included in the API output, but should not be
>   included in the input during create or update operations. Any
>   'read_only' fields that are incorrectly included in the serializer
>   input will be ignored.
>
> Set this to True to ensure that the field is used when serializing a
>   representation, but is not used when creating or updating an instance
>   during deserialization.
>
> Defaults to False