# DRF Serializer Nested Field for User Creation

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-serializer

So I have a custom model - Profile, which has a OneToOne relation with a django User object.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_type = models.CharField()
```

I want to make a django rest framework serializer which allows for creation of creation and retrieval of a User object's nested attributes as well as the "profile_type" attribute.

I want the names to be specified on the POST request as simply as "username", "password", "email", etc. - instead of "profile_username", "profile_password", ...

So far I have

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='profile_user_username')
    password = serializers.CharField(source='profile_user_password')
    email = serializers.CharField(source='profile_user_email')

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id',
                  'profile_user_username', 'profile_user_password', 'profile_user_email',
                  'username',
                  'password',
                  'email')
        depth = 2
```

But - I've been getting an error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Field name 'profile_user_username' is not valid for model 'Profile'
```

Am I getting the syntax for nested fields wrong? Or is it something else?

Comment: Did you try ```source='profile.user.username'```?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField()
    password = models.CharField()
    email = models.CharField()

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('user', 'profile_type',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = User.objects.create(**user_data)
        profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
        return profile
```

and check out 
[this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) for Writable nested serializers.

For dealing a nested object:
checkout this [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations)

Comment: Hm, no dice. I've tried other variations too - such as profile_user.username

Comment: hi, @codepringle. After carefully read your question. I think what you really want is a writable nested serializer. I have edited my answer, you can check it out if that suits your need.

Comment: Hey, so this was mostly what I needed. I'd love it if you could update your answer to include this however: in addition to making a custom UserSerializer, I also needed to override the ProfileSerializer's create(self, validated_data) method. This allowed me to access the data so I could save the proper relations in the ORM (i.e. the user, and it's relation saved on the Profile). Thanks in any case!

Comment: This question is exactly what this is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316664/drf-create-user-in-nested-serializer