# "This field is required." in DRF serializers

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am facing an issue in DRF serializers. I have a model named Issue which has a foreign Key of User Model to save the user who has created the particular Issue. Now the Get request is working fine when I request to get the issues I get it perfectly fine with username who has created the issue, but when I do the post request I get the error on "created_by" field that "This field is requied" even though I am providing this field.

Following is my code:

Model

```
class Issues(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='issue_created_by')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225, default='', null=False)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='')
    created_on = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=225, blank=True, null=True, default='')
```

Issue Serializer

```
class IssueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Issues
        fields = ['created_by', 'title', 'details', 'created_on', 'tags']
```

UserSerializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = super().create(validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return True
```

views.py

```
class IssueView(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def create(self, request):
        serialized_issues = IssueSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serialized_issues.is_valid():
            serialized_issues.save()
            return Response({'message': 'Issue Created', 'status': status.HTTP_200_OK})
        else:
            return Response({'error': serialized_issues.errors, 'status': status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST})

    def list(self, request):
        all_issues = Issues.objects.all()
        serialized_issues = IssueSerializer(all_issues, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_issues.data)
```

Comment: to make this work you need to to have a created_by field in your form. do you have that ?

Comment: I am testing it from postman and I added the created_by filed in form-data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284436/drf-serializer-nested-field-for-user-creation

Comment: Shouldn’t you be sending the data as JSON instead of form data?

Answer (score 0):

To work with a writeable nested serializer you need to overwrite the create method of the serializer. You can see the documentation [here]: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

It seems you are creating a new user with every Issue created. It is quite unrealistic. You need to pass the request.user object to the serializer while creating a new issue. The updated code may be like
method in view

````
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    created_by = request.user
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(created_by=created_by)
        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(data=serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)```


and serializer file may be like

class IssueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Issues
        fields = ['title', 'details', 'created_on', 'tags']
````